# Multiple grouped value select component

Tags: javascript, beginner, react.js, jsx

I've been designing a React component to select countries that a user has visited, grouped by continent. This component is a part of larger project but is relatively self contained. This is my first time using React (and JS really!) and I feel like passing props from the top level component down through other components is 'wrong'. Is this the correct idea in React?

**Component #1:** I want to render the menu on to a canvas.

```
const SelectCanvas = (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Offcanvas show={props.show} onHide={props.handleClose} name="Test">
          <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
            <Offcanvas.Title>Countries Visited</Offcanvas.Title>
          </Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Body>
            <CountrySelector addCountry={props.addCountry} selectedCountries={props.selectedCountries}/>
          </Offcanvas.Body>
        </Offcanvas>
      </>
    );
  }
```

**Component #2:** Read in my countries data and give the user an interface to filter the countries with a search box. Creates an expander for each continent.

```
const CountrySelector = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
    const [groupedCountries, setGroupedCountries] = useState({});
  

  useEffect(() => {
    csv(`/countries.csv`).then((data) => {
      setData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredCountries = data.filter(country => String(country.NAME).toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.toLowerCase()));
    setGroupedCountries(groupBy(filteredCountries, "CONTINENT"))
  }, [data, filter])

  function groupBy(arr, property) {
    return arr.reduce(function(memo, x) {
      if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
      memo[x[property]].push(x);
      return memo;
    }, {});
  }  

  return (
      <Form>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Control placeholder="Search country" onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}/>
        </Form.Group>
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey={0}> 
          {Object.keys(groupedCountries).map((continent, i) => (
            <Accordion.Item eventKey={i}>
              <Accordion.Header>{continent}</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body>
                <CountryList 
                  filteredCountries={groupedCountries[continent]} 
                  selectedCountries={props.selectedCountries} 
                  addCountry={props.addCountry}/>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
          ))
          }
        </Accordion>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

**Component #3:** For the array of country objects, render them as a list of checkboxes.

```
const CountryList = (props) => {
  return (
    props.filteredCountries.map((country) => (
      <Form.Check 
          key={country.ISO3}
          type='checkbox'
          id={country.ISO3}
          label={country.NAME}
          onClick={props.addCountry}
          defaultChecked={props.selectedCountries.includes(country.ISO3) ? true : false}
      />
  ))
  )
}
```

A little more info:

- The `addCountry` method thats passed in will add a country to the `selectedCountries` array. If the country is already in the array, it will remove it.
- The `'countries.csv'` file contains names, ISO3 codes, and various other bits of information about countries.
- These are the imports I'm using:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'
import {csv} from 'd3-fetch';
```

- Full repo is [here.](https://github.com/ZacLanghorne/BeenTo)

Thank you, and please let me know if I can elaborate on anything.

Answer (score 1):

[Prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) is not necessarily always wrong, but often discouraged, so I'd say your instinct is correct here.

Here's an article on how to [Avoid Prop Drilling with React Context](https://medium.com/swlh/avoid-prop-drilling-with-react-context-a00392ee3d8) making use of React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which should be exactly what you're looking for here. If you prefer video over text, this [video tutorial by WebDev Simplified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc) (13 minutes) should be a good starting point.